# rbash for ssh ldap users

Tags: bash, centos, ldap, restricted-shell

I have some ssh ldap users who connect to my server (centos7) for reset their password.
I would like they use rbash for execute `passwd` command but I don't know how to do.
I can't add `rbash` to `/etc/passwd` because they are LDAP user and they are not in this file.

I thought of 2 solutions, but not very safe:

- Launch rbash (or passwd command) in sshd_config with 'ForceCommand'
- Launch rbash in /etc/profile

Comment: thanks @Archemar. I added in /etc/sssd/sssd.conf : 
`[nss]
allowed_shell = /bin/rbash
default_shell = /bin/rbash
override_shell = /bin/rbash
vetoed_shells = /bin/rbash
shell_fallback = /bin/rbash`

Answer (score 0):

went I set Active directory, I had to use samba.

In `samba.conf` there is a parameter called `template shell`, have you tried setting it ?

```
[global]
(...)
realm = MYREALM
template shell = /sbin/rbash
```